# Differences between getConnection() ad getConnection(String username, String password)

Tags: tomcat, connection, database-connection, connection-pooling, sqldatasource

On a DataSource interface I found two methods to get Connection, with and without username and password paramenters.

```
Connection getConnection()
Connection getConnection(String username, String password)
```

Stated that I'd like to use a connection pool exposed as JNDI Resource from the server (tomcat) what differences are from the two methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the `DataSource` implementation, these two methods do different things. The first, with no arguments, simply obtains a `Connection` from the pool, configured with credentials configured when the `DataSource` was created. The second, which accepts *new* credentials, will obtain a Connection from the `DataSource` that was opened using those credentials, or it will create a new `Connection` with those credentials or -- if the JDBC driver supports it -- it will take an existing `Connection` and switch the credentials (I'm not sure if this is really even possible).

Unfortunately, the JavaDoc (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sql/DataSource.html) does not really give you any insight to why one might call one versus the other. The obvious reason is because you want to connect using credentials other than those configured for the entire `DataSource`.

The default `DataSource` that Tomcat will configure for you is a `BasicDataSource` from the Apache `commons-dbcp`: this DataSource does not support the `getConnection(String username, String password)` method. Recent versions of Tomcat ship with `tomcat-pool`, which is an alternative DataSource implementation that *does* support this alternative mechanism (although the current documentation says it does not) if you set the `alternateUsernameAllowed="true"` attribute on your `<Resource>` element.

Tomcat-pool documentation: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html

Comment: If I understand well, using the method without parameters I'll have connection from a pool while the latter does not (create a new connection every call)?
That is just what I need to know, can someone confirm that?
Is there somewhere some documentation of that?

Comment: I gave you a link to the documentation and mentioned the `alternateUsernameAllowed` attribute. Please read the documentation for that attribute which explains exactly what happens when you call `getConnection(String,String)`.

Answer (score 0):

This is method overloading.

[**Connection getConnection()**](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/tomcat/jdbc/pool/ConnectionPool.html#getConnection%28%29)

Borrows a connection from the pool. If a connection is available (in the idle queue) or the   pool has not reached maxActive connections a connection is returned immediately. If no connection is available, the pool will attempt to fetch a connection for maxWait milliseconds.

**Returns:** Connection - a java.sql.Connection/javax.sql.PooledConnection reflection proxy, wrapping the underlying object.

[**getConnection(String username, String password)**](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/tomcat/jdbc/pool/ConnectionPool.html#getConnection%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Borrows a connection from the pool. If a connection is available (in the idle queue) or the pool has not reached maxActive connections a connection is returned immediately. If no connection is available, the pool will attempt to fetch a connection for maxWait milliseconds.

Comment: it seems they are the same?
But it is strange for me, if when I configure the pooler I'll give it a credential so it (the pooler) can acquire a pool of connection, then the developer can get a connection from the pool but with others credential? is it rigth?